# visual studio 2012: Help needed with projects and solution explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, project, solution-explorer

Hi iam new to visiual studio, and for my studies i have one centered with c#.It is not a difficult questions

firstly wheneveri start a new project through file->NEW->projects all other projects in the document disapears. anyway to keep them?

secondly whenever without any problem when i start new projects the solution explorer shows its contexts without problem, but how do i show the contents of other projects opened aswell?

thanks in advance hope it is not vague.

Answer (score 2):

By doing this "file->NEW->projects" you are opening a new solution if you don't
change the solution property to "Create new solution" to "Add to solution".

[image: Create new solution]

[image: Add to solution]

By selecting "Add to solution" you can add new project to you existing solution.
also you can right click the existing solution and add new project to it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your solution and then click on Add. Then select Existing project and add your project into the solution. Then you will be able to see all the projects opened at the same time.